# Import error: Cannot import PerfectoLibrary

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, robotframework, perfecto

I am unable to import the PerfectoLibrary. I get the following error:

```
[ ERROR ] Error in file 'C:\Pipelines\obrexternal-testautomation\OBRRobotFramework_Mobile\Resources\common\OBRKeywords_Mobile.robot': Importing test library 'PerfectoLibrary' failed: ImportError: cannot import name 'quote_plus' from 'urllib' (C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\urllib\__init__.py)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\PerfectoLibrary\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
from PerfectoLibrary.keywords import *
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\PerfectoLibrary\keywords\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
from ._rest_acts import _RestKeywords
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\PerfectoLibrary\keywords\_rest_acts.py", line 15, in <module>
from urllib import quote_plus
PYTHONPATH:
  C:\Pipelines\obrexternal-testautomation\OBRRobotFramework_Mobile\Resources\common
```

C:\Pipelines\obrexternal-testautomation\OBRRobotFramework_Mobile\Resources\common
C:\Pipelines\obrexternal-testautomation\OBRRobotFramework_Mobile
C:\Pipelines\EDO-testautomation\RobotFramework
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\python37.zip
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\DLLs
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32
C:\Users\hawesc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin

I am trying to run mobile tests through Perfecto:

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation     WARNING! This is a library File.
Library    XML
Library    String
Library    Collections
Library    AppiumLibrary
Library    SeleniumLibrary
Library    DateTime
Library    BuiltIn
Library    OperatingSystem
Library    PythonLibraries/CustomKeywords.py
Library    PerfectoLibrary
Variables  PythonLibraries/MainListener.py
Variables  PythonLibraries/CustomVariables.py   
Variables  PythonLibraries/Locators.py
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of
ImportError: cannot import name 'quote_plus' from 'urllib'
I assume you use this:

```
from urllib import quote_plus
```

replace that line with this:

```
from urllib.parse import quote_plus
```

Works fine on me if it doesnt please comment your python version

Comment: Let me know if this works for you or if you need further help